# Reference website live updating status from App

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiwebview, web

I have a website: http://www.grandforks.af.mil/library/weathercenter/index.asp

There is a logo on the middle of the page for the current road conditions on base.

The file names for each condition is different by 1 number.

- Green is 19
- Yellow is 20
- Red is 21

I do not have control over this website.

My question is how can I have the current road conditions in an app that I am building display as a reflection of the website?  I don't want to have any user input I want the app to be able to pull off of the site.  I have tried using UIWebView but I cannot get it to focus on that area of the page. If I could do that it would probably be the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly solution:
you can download the html of the website, parse it searching the string "http://www.grandforks.af.mil/shared/media/document/AFD-121002-" and get the actual URL (which is something like http://www.grandforks.af.mil/shared/media/document/AFD-121002-019.jpg).
After that, you can load that URL in your UIImageView or (better) discriminate and show your image that is included in the app.

The ugliness depends by the fact that if they change the image's URL, your app stops working.

I would suggest that when the user opens the app, it goes to check your page and eventually download the string your are looking for. Doing so, if the website changes the url, you can manually modify the source without update the app.

I don't know if using others information is legal.

---

**EDIT:
here is an example that I built that demonstrate how you can substring a string:**

```
NSString *myString = @"11111www.the-site.com/img42.jpg222222222222222";
NSString *searchString = @"www.the-site.com/img";
NSRange range = [myString rangeOfString:searchString];
NSLog(@"searched string strart at character %lu, and it's long %lu charactrers", (unsigned long)range.location, (unsigned long)range.length);
NSInteger index = range.location + range.length;
NSString *mySubString = [myString substringFromIndex:index];
NSLog(@"string from the index: %@", mySubString);
//I know that the substring I'm looking for is long exactly 2 characters
NSString *the_answer = [mySubString substringToIndex:2];
NSLog(@"this should print 42: %@", the_answer);
```

I added some prints, so you can see step by step what I'm doing.
Obviously you have to change "searchString" with "http://www.grandforks.af.mil/shared/media/document/AFD-121002-" and myString is the html of the page.

I hope it helps.

Comment: So I am a little new to the parsing.  Is there any way you could try helping me?  I am not asking you to write my app or anything.  Just maybe help me improve my skills and app.